# Enable all Safari extensions from Terminal

Tags: safari, macos, safari-extensions

For various reasons that aren't important, whenever my MacBook reboots, Safari extensions are disabled. I can manually go into the `Develop` menu, and uncheck `Disable Extensions`, and that work just fine, but its annoying and an extra step that I have to remember.

I wrote a simple script that checks the output of `defaults read com.apple.Safari ExtensionsEnabled`

and if it is 0, runs `defaults write com.apple.safari ExtensionsEnabled 1`

This all works and it does indeed set that parameter to 1, but Safari does not actually enable my extensions, `Develop` - `Disable Extensions` remains checked, and my extension icons don't appear. Restarting Safari after running it does not help either.

So is there a cache I need to clear somewhere for Safari to re-read the plist and enable extensions?

I've also considered writing an applescript that would just simulate the human interaction, but the laptop is locked down and I can't add it to accessibilities due to no permissions, so that's a no-go.